# Unpack rar archives in R

Tags: r, zip, rstudio, unpack, rar

I need to unpack zip and rar archives, also that must be a multiplatform solution.

In R you can unpack zip easily by command

```
unzip(filename, exdir=‘’)
```

But I found I can’t unpack rar files that way.
On OS X I can simply open archive to unpack it, if I have unarchiver configured that way:

```
system(paste("open", path))
```

I googled, that 7zip can be installed and do unpacking from console, so I’ve tried installr package for Windows

```
require(installr)
install.7zip()
system(paste("7z x", path))
```

but I get warning and nothing happens

```
running command '7z x 1.rar’ had status 127
```

and terminal command for Unix

```
system('sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar')
system(paste("7z x ", path))
```

but it returned error with sudo

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628844/how-to-read-file-rar-directly-from-website-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support unpacking RAR archives on any platform by your own application I suggest to integrate **UnRAR source** code into your application. The source code is written in C++. So you would need to compile this source code for all platforms with a C++ compiler and add the generated application to your R application package.

Well, there is also free *UnRAR* for Windows (x86 and x64), Linux, Mac OS X and other operating systems for various processors on [WinRAR and RAR archiver addons](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) page. So you could create also a package with your R app and suitable *UnRAR* application for each platform you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar
```

in a terminal,  you have an error because in rstudio, you cannot be asked for your password.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use `untar` to unpack a RAR file.

But in Linux, I failed. Still trying to fix it.