# Download a xlsx file that is inside a zip file from website in R

Tags: r, 7zip

I am working in R, trying to get a national index from Uruguay that i need to calculate constant prices.

Before i used the fil function from the httr package and the next line of code:

```
fil= GET("https://www.ine.gub.uy/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=ed831b06-8dbd-437c-81cf-c814b4248b06&groupId=10181", 
write_disk("ine.xlsx", overwrite = T))
```

and with this, all the job was done.

The problem is that recently the webpage changed and now the file that I used to download,
it is a zip file and I am now struggling to get an excel file from inside the zip.

Here i left the url direction. url :

```
https://www5.ine.gub.uy/documents/Estad%C3%ADsticasecon%C3%B3micas/SERIES%20Y%20OTROS/IPC/Base%20Octubre%202022=100/IPC%20-%20Base%20Octubre%202022=100.rar
```

I have tried with archive package and with download file but i cant even get closer to my goal.

Any advice?

In case one of you wonder, the file that i want from inside the zip it is the next one:
`IPC General_Total Pais_Montevideo_Interior_base 2022.xlsx`

And another fact its that i have 7-zip in my pc. Dont know if it changes something.

Already thanks!

Comment: I have seen that answer but when i try to apply it, i get this error: "Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open zip file 'C:\Users\EMILIA~1.BAR\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWM4yae\file49c46506dba'"

Comment: @SamR I forgot to add the new url of the file that i want to access.

Comment: OK if it's an rar rather than zip see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628844/how-to-read-file-rar-directly-from-website-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a *Rar* archive, saving it as something else (like zip) potentially confuses extractors. And if you happened to use `download.file()`, you most likely have to use it with `mode = "wb"`, at least with the default download method on Windows:

> The choice of binary transfer (`mode = "wb"` or `"ab"`) is important on Windows, since unlike Unix-alikes it does distinguish between text and binary files and for text transfers changes \n line endings to \r\n (aka ‘CRLF’).

Though with `archive` package you can just point it to URL, if you don't want to keep the archive:

```r
rar  <- "https://www5.ine.gub.uy/documents/Estad%C3%ADsticasecon%C3%B3micas/SERIES%20Y%20OTROS/IPC/Base%20Octubre%202022=100/IPC%20-%20Base%20Octubre%202022=100.rar"
filename <- "IPC General_Total Pais_Montevideo_Interior_base 2022.xlsx"
archive::archive_extract(archive = rar, 
                         dir = tempdir(), 
                         files = filename)
readxl::read_xlsx(file.path(tempdir(), filename))
#> Warning: Expecting numeric in A1032 / R1032C1: got 'Fuente: Instituto Nacional
#> de Estadística (INE).'
#> # A tibble: 1,031 × 5
#>      Año   Mes `General Total Pais` `General Montevideo` `General Interior`
#>    <dbl> <dbl>                <dbl> <chr>                <chr>             
#>  1  1937     7          0.000000159 ..                   ..                
#>  2  1937     8          0.000000160 ..                   ..                
#>  3  1937     9          0.000000159 ..                   ..                
#>  4  1937    10          0.000000160 ..                   ..                
#>  5  1937    11          0.000000161 ..                   ..                
#>  6  1937    12          0.000000161 ..                   ..                
#>  7  1938     1          0.000000162 ..                   ..                
#>  8  1938     2          0.000000156 ..                   ..                
#>  9  1938     3          0.000000155 ..                   ..                
#> 10  1938     4          0.000000155 ..                   ..                
#> # ℹ 1,021 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much!! I spent a lot of time trying to get this. Very appreciated